# Can't figure how to adapt my javascript code from codepen to Atom

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, constants

I just build this simple testimonial slider with stars review on codepen.io

https://codepen.io/Nalid/pen/abdaqvR

While incorporating the code into the website I'm building on my text editor (Atom), everything works fine, except that the javascript does not seem to be executed, I tried changing " document.querySelector" for "document.getElementByID" or ".getElementByClassName "; on code pen it is working properly but on Atom, again it is not working, worst it moves to the top my next and preview button.

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div data-carousel>
        <ul class="slide__list Wallop-list">
            <li class="slide__item Wallop-item Wallop-item--current">
                    <h2 class="slide__heading">Norma C.</h2>
                    <blockquote>
                        <p class="slide__quote">He estado buscando durante años un buen médico con respecto a la mamografía y otros tratamientos para mujeres, el Dr. Ramos fue el mejor experimentado con cualquier duda, sabiamente recomiendo su servicio, ¡el mejor médico de la ciudad!</p>
                        <div class="Stars slide__cite" style="--rating: 4.3;" aria-label="Rating of this product is 5 out of 5."></div>
            </li>
            <li class="slide__item Wallop-item">
                <h2 class="slide__heading">Priscila G.</h2>
                <blockquote>
                    <p class="slide__quote">El Dr. Ramos me lo recomendó un amigo, es muy profesional y siempre está dispuesto a ayudar, incluso fuera de su horario de trabajo, tiene muy buen equipo y es muy profesional.</p>
                    <div class="Stars slide__cite" style="--rating: 5;" aria-label="Rating of this product is 5 out of 5."></div>
                </blockquote>
            </li>
            <li class="slide__item Wallop-item">
                <h2 class="slide__heading">Dilan M.</h2>
                    <blockquote>
                        <p class="slide__quote">Soy de Francia y estoy acostumbrado a un hospital y servicio de alto nivel, y podría decir que los estándares y la profesionalidad del Dr. Ramos son más altos que la mayoría de los médicos y hospitales en Europa.</p>
                        <div class="Stars slide__cite" style="--rating: 4;" aria-label="Rating of this product is 5 out of 5.">
                    </blockquote>
            </li>
            <li class="slide__item Wallop-item">
                <h2 class="slide__heading">Margarita C.</h2>
                    <blockquote>
                        <p class="slide__quote">Llegué por primera vez al Dr. Ramos con la consulta gratuita en línea, se detectará un posible cáncer de mama, planeamos una cita en su consultorio al día siguiente, después de una cirugía unas semanas después, puedo decir que estoy fuera de peligro, GRACIAS TANTO doctor Ramos</p>
                        <div class="Stars slide__cite" style="--rating: 5;" aria-label="Rating of this product is 5 out of 5."></div>
                    </blockquote>
            </li>
            <li class="slide__item Wallop-item">
                <h2 class="slide__heading">Xochitl G.</h2>
                <blockquote>
                    <p class="slide__quote">He visto al Dr. Ramos en su oficina después de una consulta gratuita en línea emitida por Skype, me proporcionó un check-up ginecológico completo, seguramente lo recomendaré.</p>
                    <div class="Stars slide__cite" style="--rating: 5;" aria-label="Rating of this product is 5 out of 5."></div>
                </blockquote>
            </li>
            <li class="slide__item Wallop-item">
                <h2 class="slide__heading">Vanessa L.</h2>
                <blockquote>
                    <p class="slide__quote">Mucho mejor que cualquier otro oncólogo en Cancún, estoy hablando de experiencia.</p>
                    <div class="Stars slide__cite" style="--rating: 4.5;" aria-label="Rating of this product is 4 out of 5."></div>
                </blockquote>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <button class="button--prev Wallop-buttonPrevious btnRV" title="previous">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 27.9 50.2"><path d="M25.1 50.2L0 25.1 25.1 0l2.8 2.8L5.7 25.1l22.2 22.2z"/></svg>
        </button>
        <button class="button--next Wallop-buttonNext btnRV" title="next">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 27.9 50.2"><path d="M25.1 50.2L0 25.1 25.1 0l2.8 2.8L5.7 25.1l22.2 22.2z"/></svg>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<div class="reviewContainer">
    <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="w3-button btnR w3-large">Agregar una opinión</button>
    
</div>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

<div class="w3-container">
  

  <div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
    <div class="w3-modal-content w3-card-4 w3-animate-zoom" style="max-width:600px">

      <div class="w3-center"><br>
        <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="w3-button w3-xlarge w3-hover-red w3-display-topright" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
        
      </div>

      <form class="w3-container" action="/action_page.php">
        <div class="w3-section">
          <label><b>Nombre</b></label>
          <input class="w3-input w3-border w3-margin-bottom" type="text"  name="name" required>
          <label><b>Comentario</b></label>
          <textarea name="comment" class="w3-input w3-border w3-margin-bottom"></textarea>
             <label><b>Clasification</b></label>
          <div class="rating">
            <input id="star5" name="star" type="radio" value="5" class="radio-btn hide" />
            <label for="star5" >☆</label>
            <input id="star4" name="star" type="radio" value="4" class="radio-btn hide" />
            <label for="star4" >☆</label>
            <input id="star3" name="star" type="radio" value="3" class="radio-btn hide" />
            <label for="star3" >☆</label>
            <input id="star2" name="star" type="radio" value="2" class="radio-btn hide" />
            <label for="star2" >☆</label>
            <input id="star1" name="star" type="radio" value="1" class="radio-btn hide" />
            <label for="star1" >☆</label>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
<div class="txt-center">
          </div>
    </form>
             
          <button class="w3-button w3-block submitR w3-section w3-padding w3-margin-50" name="submit" type="submit">Enviar</button>
          
        </div>
      </form>

      <div class="w3-container w3-border-top w3-padding-16 w3-light-grey">
       
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
@import url('https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');

p {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

/* List reset */
ul {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

button  {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    width: 65px;
    padding: 20px;
    transition: opacity 200ms;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
    z-index: 2;
    
    svg {
        fill: #5ac3ca;
    }
    
    &:hover,
    &:focus {
        opacity: 0.6;
    }
}

.button--next {
    left: auto;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0) rotate(180deg);
}

.wrapper {
    height: 100vh;
    min-height: 600px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-column: 5;
}

.slide__list {
    width: calc(100vw - 40px);
    height: calc(100vw / 2);
    font-family: Lato, sans-serif;
    
    &::before,
    &::after {
        content: '';
        width: 180px;
        height: 100%;
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    
    &::before {
        left: 0;
        background: none;
    }
    
    &::after {
        right: 0;
        background: none;
    }
}

.slide__item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 40px 65px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    
    > * {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

.slide__heading,
.slide__quote,
.slide__cite {
    opacity: 0;
    animation-timing-function: var(--originalCurve);
    width: calc(100% - 120px);
    max-width: 600px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.slide__heading {
    --delay: 300ms;
    
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
}
    
.slide__quote {
    --delay: 420ms;
    
    font-size: 1.1rem;
    line-height: 1.4;
    letter-spacing: 0.03em;
}

.slide__cite {
    --delay: 540ms;
    
    display: block;
}

[data-carousel] {
  position: relative;
}

.Wallop-list {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Wallop-item {
    --x1: 0.1;
  --y1: 0.67;
  --x2: 0.29;
  --y2: 0.98;
  
  --originalCurve: cubic-bezier(var(--x1), var(--y1), var(--x2), var(--y2));
    --reversedCurve: cubic-bezier(calc(1 - var(--x2)), calc(1 - var(--y2)), calc(1 - var(--x1)), calc(1 - var(--y1)));
    
    --length: 1300ms;
    
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.Wallop-item--current {
  visibility: visible;
  position: relative;
    
    .slide__heading,
    .slide__quote,
    .slide__cite {
        animation: slideIn var(--length) forwards var(--originalCurve);
    }
}

.Wallop-item--showPrevious {
  .slide__heading,
    .slide__quote,
    .slide__cite {
        animation: slideOut var(--length) var(--delay) forwards reverse var(--reversedCurve);
    }
}

.Wallop-item--showNext {
    .slide__heading,
    .slide__quote,
    .slide__cite {
        animation: slideIn var(--length) var(--delay) forwards var(--originalCurve);
    }
}

.Wallop-item--hidePrevious,
.Wallop-item--hideNext {
    --length: 500ms;
  visibility: visible;
}

.Wallop-item--hidePrevious {
    .slide__heading,
    .slide__quote,
    .slide__cite {
        animation: slideOut var(--length) forwards var(--originalCurve);
    }
}

.Wallop-item--hideNext {
    .slide__heading,
    .slide__quote,
    .slide__cite {
        animation: slideIn var(--length) forwards reverse var(--reversedCurve);
    }
}


/* Custom keyframe animation */

@keyframes slideIn {
    0% {
        transform: translate3d(50%, 0, 0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes slideOut {
    0% {
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
        opacity: 1;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translate3d(-50%, 0, 0);
        opacity: 0;
    }
}

:root {
  --star-size: 60px;
  --star-color: rgba(207, 207, 207, 0.55);
  --star-background: #fc0;
}

.Stars {
  --percent: calc(var(--rating) / 5 * 100%);
    display: inline-block;
  font-size: var(--star-size);
  font-family: Times; // make sure ★ appears correctly
  line-height: 1;
    font-size: 2vw;  
  &::before {
    content: '★★★★★';
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, var(--star-background) var(--percent), var(--star-color) var(--percent));
    -webkit-background-clip: text;
    -webkit-text-fill-color:transparent;
  }
}


.txt-center {
  text-align: center;
}
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.clear {
  float: none;
  clear: both;
}

.rating {
    width: 90px;
    unicode-bidi: bidi-override;
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.rating > label {
    float: right;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 1.1em;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #000;
}

.rating > label:hover,
.rating > label:hover ~ label,
.rating > input.radio-btn:checked ~ label {
    color: transparent;
}

.rating > label:hover:before,
.rating > label:hover ~ label:before,
.rating > input.radio-btn:checked ~ label:before,
.rating > input.radio-btn:checked ~ label:before {
    content: "\2605";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    color: #FFD700;
}
.clR{
  text-align: left !important;
}
.btnR{
  background-color: #5ac3ca !important;
  color:white !important;
}
.submitR{
  background-color: #5ac3ca !important;
  color: white !important;
    grid-column: 5 / 10;
}

.reviewContainer{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(10, 10vw);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 10vh);
    border: 4px solid red;
    margin-top: -25vh;
}
```

Javascript:

```
const slider = document.querySelector('[data-carousel]');
const slides = [...document.querySelectorAll('.Wallop-item')]
this.wallop = new Wallop(slider); 

let prev = 0 

const removePrevClasses = (index) => {
    let prevClass
    if (slides[index].classList.contains('Wallop-item--hidePrevious')) {
        prevClass = 'Wallop-item--hidePrevious'
    } else if (slides[index].classList.contains('Wallop-item--hideNext')) {
        prevClass = 'Wallop-item--hideNext'
    }
    
    if (prevClass) {
        setTimeout(() => {
        slides[index].classList.remove(prevClass)
    }, 600)
    }
}

const onChange = () => {
    removePrevClasses(prev)
    prev = this.wallop.currentItemIndex
}

this.wallop.on('change', onChange);

//Reviews

let focusedElementBeforeModal;
var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
var modalOverlay = document.querySelector('.modal-overlay');

window.onload = () => {
  var addReview = document.getElementById('review-add-btn');
  addReview.id = 'review-add-btn';
  addReview.innerHTML = '+';
  addReview.setAttribute('aria-label', 'add review');
  addReview.title = 'Add Review';
  addReview.addEventListener('click', openModal);
 // addReview.click();
} 

var openModal = () => {
  // Save current focus
  focusedElementBeforeModal = document.activeElement;

  // Listen for and trap the keyboard
  modal.addEventListener('keydown', trapTabKey);

  // Listen for indicators to close the modal
  modalOverlay.addEventListener('click', closeModal);
  // Close btn
  var closeBtn = document.querySelector('.close-btn');
  closeBtn.addEventListener('click', closeModal);

  
  
  // Convert NodeList to Array
  focusableElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(focusableElements);

  var firstTabStop = focusableElements[0];
  var lastTabStop = focusableElements[focusableElements.length - 1];

  // Show the modal and overlay
  modal.classList.add('show');
  modalOverlay.classList.add('show');

  // Focus first child
  // firstTabStop.focus();
  var reviewName = document.getElementById('reviewName');
  reviewName.focus();

  function trapTabKey(e) {
    // Check for TAB key press
    if (e.keyCode === 9) {

      // SHIFT + TAB
      if (e.shiftKey) {
        if (document.activeElement === firstTabStop) {
          e.preventDefault();
          lastTabStop.focus();
        }

      // TAB
      } else {
        if (document.activeElement === lastTabStop) {
          e.preventDefault();
          firstTabStop.focus();
        }
      }
    }

    // ESCAPE
    if (e.keyCode === 27) {
      closeModal();
    }
  }
};

var submitAddReview = (e) => {
  // console.log(e);
  console.log('Form subbmitted!');
  e.preventDefault();
  closeModal();
};

var closeModal = () => {
  // Hide the modal and overlay
  modal.classList.remove('show');
  modalOverlay.classList.remove('show');

  var form = document.getElementById('review-form');
  form.reset();
  // Set focus back to element that had it before the modal was opened
  focusedElementBeforeModal.focus();
};

var setFocus = (evt) => {
  var rateRadios = document.getElementsByName('rate');
  var rateRadiosArr = Array.from(rateRadios);
  var anyChecked = rateRadiosArr.some(radio => { return radio.checked === true; });
  // console.log('anyChecked', anyChecked);
  if (!anyChecked) {
    var star1 = document.getElementById('star1');
    star1.focus();
    // star1.checked = true;
  }
};

var navRadioGroup = (evt) => {
  // console.log('key', evt.key, 'code', evt.code, 'which', evt.which);
  // console.log(evt);
  
  var star1 = document.getElementById('star1');  
  var star2 = document.getElementById('star2');  
  var star3 = document.getElementById('star3');  
  var star4 = document.getElementById('star4');  
  var star5 = document.getElementById('star5');  

  if (['ArrowRight', 'ArrowLeft', 'ArrowDown', 'ArrowUp'].includes(evt.key)) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    // console.log('attempting return');
    if (evt.key === 'ArrowRight' || evt.key === 'ArrowDown') {
      switch(evt.target.id) {
        case 'star1':
          star2.focus();
          star2.checked = true;
          break;
        case 'star2':
          star3.focus();
          star3.checked = true;
          break;
        case 'star3':
          star4.focus();
          star4.checked = true;
          break;
        case 'star4':
          star5.focus();
          star5.checked = true;
          break;
        case 'star5':
          star1.focus();
          star1.checked = true;
          break;
      }
    } else if (evt.key === 'ArrowLeft' || evt.key === 'ArrowUp') {
      switch(evt.target.id) {
        case 'star1':
          star5.focus();
          star5.checked = true;
          break;
        case 'star2':
          star1.focus();
          star1.checked = true;
          break;
        case 'star3':
          star2.focus();
          star2.checked = true;
          break;
        case 'star4':
          star3.focus();
          star3.checked = true;
          break;
        case 'star5':
          star4.focus();
          star4.checked = true;
          break;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Your Pen settings show you are using SCSS and linking to _wallop_. Have you included these dependencies in your code?

Comment: God damned it Charles !
That was it..
I just added <script src="https://cdn.tutorialjinni.com/wallop/2.4.1/js/Wallop.js"></script> to my head tag and it is almost working, just my slides are not moving properly I'll work on it, thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well,
Sometimes, you spend soo much time looking for a answer, you think you look everywhere, but you look for the most complicated way , but it was in fact simple..
I just added

```
<script src="cdn.tutorialjinni.com/wallop/2.4.1/js/Wallop.js"></>
```

into my head tag and it's now working.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be missing is including the javascript code in the HTML document (codepen might be doing it for you)

Can you wrap your JavaScript code in a  tag and include it at the bottom your HTML document and try again?

Example:

```
<script>
  // The JavaScript from codepen goes here!
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
I already try this as well as putting the code into my main.js with the rest of my javascript ; nothing is working :/

Comment: I see. Did you debug step by step? I would add console logs in the event listener say `openModal`. If that's not getting invoked then check if  the element `addReview` in `window.onload` is the expected one and if that doesn't work, check if `window.onload` is being invoked in the first place!
You can do these steps in the reverse order as well

Comment: Well, it was a dummy mistake from me as said Charles "Your Pen settings show you are using SCSS and linking to wallop. Have you included these dependencies in your code?"
I just add <script src="cdn.tutorialjinni.com/wallop/2.4.1/js/Wallop.js"></…> into my head tag and it's almot perfectly working now, just my slides transition is not great but I'll work on it.
I feel very dumb ahaha